# A ordem das cláusulas WHERE interfere na performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, query, otimização

Recentemente fiz uns testes em uma base de dados com uma query utilizando duas cláusulas where AND. Notei que houve uma significativa diferença usando a cláusula A antes da B e vice-versa.

Intuitivamente, seria mais rápido utilizar PRIMEIRO o critério mais restritivo, pois teria um conjunto menor para nele então aplicar o segundo critério. Por exemplo, tomando como base a população brasileira economicamente ativa, se eu quiser obter todos os registros do sexo 'masculino' com 'renda superior a 1 milhão de dólares' seria mais rápido eu primeiro filtrar os registros pela renda para só depois filtrar pelo sexo.

Fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei esse [tópico](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57655/why-should-the-most-restrictive-condition-be-listed-last-in-the-where-clause) dizendo que não há diferença entre usar uma depois da outra, mas não foi o que constatei na prática. Tenho uma tabela com quase 2 milhões de registros. Se eu utilizo a cláusula mais restritiva antes da menos restritiva, gasto menos de 1 segundo na query, em contraste ao usar a menos restritiva antes, quando a pesquisa leva quase 20 segundos. E estou usando a cláusula SQL_NO_CACHE na query, isto é, não estou usando cache. Fiz a inversão que eles sugerem e obtive o mesmo resultado, contrariando o que foi dito lá.

Alguém pode me explicar?

**UPDATE (1)**

Estou usando MySQL 5 nos meus testes.

Comment: E como estão suas tabelas e seus índices? E coloque as *queries* também. Provavelmente você tem um problema específico.

Comment: Quais são as condições? O MySQL faz algumas optimizações, dependendo das cláusulas http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html

Comment: Coloque as informações faltantes antes que encha de respostas chutando coisas aleatórias.

Comment: Não estou usando índices na tabela. Vou tentar montar um esquema semelhante para postar aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Ambas as clausulas fazem uso de colunas indexadas?

O código SQL e compilado e o SGDB monta um plano de execução.
Existem algumas ferramentas que permitem visulalizar o plano de execução.
No Mysql se não me engano o MySQL Workbench faz isso.
Compare o plano de execução de ambas as consultas, se forem diferentes justificara o tempo de resposta.

Também vai te mostrar como o SGDB funciona internamente.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde! Bom não sei se está certo mas vamos lá !
Quando você usa uma cláusula WHERE e busca pelo registro que provavelmente ira ter mais dados, o SQL virá mais carregado, pois, ele busca por todos as "pessoas" que são do sexo masculino, como sabemos é bem maior a quantidade de registros do que uma pessoa que ganha mais de 1 Milhão por mês, logo se você usar o filtro do salário antes irá ser mais rápido devido a diferença de quantidade de dados.
Acho que e isso, Abraço !

Answer (score 0):

Sim, pode haver diferença de performance de acordo com a ordem do WHERE. O MySQL tenta otimizar o query, nem sempre atingindo o melhor plano possível.

Uma forma de você entender o que ocorre é usar o [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html), que vai te detalhar a otimização feita. A falta de índices provavelmente faz com que não exista uma otimização óbvia e o MySQL segue a ordem original do query. Note que uma tabela com 2 milhões de registros não ter índice é provavelmente uma decisão ruim.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, tente colocar sempre como a primeira clausula datas de referencias para consultas muito grandes.. você ganhará bastante performace.